# Print out array in table widget

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer

How to print out 1d array in table widget? I have array `Sum_main`(float data) and table `table_Sum`. Table has 1 col and 5 rows.

I tried this:

```
item=self.ui.table_Sum(str(Sum_main))
for row in range(5):
    self.ui.table_Sum.setItem(row, 0, self.ui.table_Sum.item(str(Sum_main[row][0])))
```

But get error: TypeError: 'QTableWidget' object is not callable.

I have `textEdit` but I call them using `self.ui.textEdit`.
When I changed code to this, my array print out fully in each row with square brackets at start and end([]):

```
for row in range(5):
    item=QTableWidgetItem(str(Sum_main))
    self.ui.table_Sum.setItem(row, 0, item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for row in range(5): 
    item=QTableWidgetItem(str(Sum_main[row]))           
    self.ui.table_Sum.setItem(row, 0, item)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why it solved the problem, for future users :)